# Salat and Embeded MongoDb Documents

Tags: scala, mongodb, playframework, playframework-2.0, salat

I have a case class that is made up of 2 embeded documents, one of which is a list. I am having some problems retriving the items in the list.

Please see my code below:

```
package models

import play.api.Play.current
import com.novus.salat._
import com.novus.salat.dao._
import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._
import se.radley.plugin.salat._
import com.novus.salat.global._

case class Category(
  _id: ObjectId = new ObjectId,
  category: Categories,
  subcategory: List[SubCategories]
)

case class Categories(
  category_id: String,
  category_name: String
  )

case class SubCategories(
  subcategory_id: String,
  subcategory_name: String
)

object Category extends ModelCompanion[Category, ObjectId] {
  val collection = mongoCollection("category")
  val dao = new SalatDAO[Category, ObjectId](collection = collection) {}
  val CategoryDAO = dao

  def options: Seq[(String,String)] = {
    find(MongoDBObject.empty).map(it => (it.category.category_id, it.category.category_name)).toSeq
  }

  def suboptions: Seq[(String,String,String)] = {
    find(MongoDBObject.empty).map(it => (it.category.category_id, it.subcategory.subcategory_id, it.subcategory.subcategory_name)).toSeq
  }
}
```

I get the error: `value subcategory_id is not a member of List[models.SubCategories]` which doesnt make any sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing this:

```
def suboptions: Seq[(String,String,String)] = {
  find(MongoDBObject.empty).map(category => {
    val categories: Categories = category.category
    val categoryId: String = categories.category._id
    val subcategory: List[Subcategory] = category.subcategory
    val subcategoryId: String = subcategory.subcategory_id //here you are trying to 
      //get id from list of subcategories, not one of them
    val subcategoryName: String = subcategory.subcategory_name //same here
    (categoryId, subcategoryId, subcategoryName)).toSeq  
  }
}
```

BTW. using snake_case in Scala is quite uncommon, val/var names should be in camelCase, see [this](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html#values_variable_and_methods)

Edit: You can make it simple by doing this:

```
case class Category(
  _id: ObjectId = new ObjectId(), 
  id: String,
  name: String,
  subcategories: List[Subcategory]
)
case class Subcategory(
  id: String,
  name: String
)
//not tested
def suboptions: Seq[(String, String, String)] = {
  val categories = find(MongoDBObject.empty)
  for{
    category <- categories;
    subcategory <- category.subcategories
  } yield (category.id, subcategory.id, subcategory.name)
}
```